# Idle dyno still using free hours

Tags: heroku

As in topic, looks like my free dyno (I have only 1 dyno on my heroku account) uses free dyno hours when idle. Checked it and below you can see:

```
[user@host ~]$ heroku ps -a myapp
Free dyno hours quota remaining this month: 421h 16m (76%)
Free dyno usage for this app: 128h 43m (23%)
For more information on dyno sleeping and how to upgrade, see:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping

=== web (Free): npm start (1)
web.1: up 2022/04/23 23:03:34 +0200 (~ 1m ago)

[user@host ~]$ heroku ps -a myapp
Free dyno hours quota remaining this month: 394h 53m (71%)
Free dyno usage for this app: 155h 5m (28%)
For more information on dyno sleeping and how to upgrade, see:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping

=== web (Free): npm start (1)
web.1: idle 2022/04/23 23:36:32 +0200 (~ 15h ago)

[user@host ~]$ date
Sun Apr 24 15:32:04 CEST 2022
```

Which basically says that at `2022/04/23 23:03:34 +0200` I had `421h 16m` remaining
Now `Sun Apr 24 15:32:04 CEST 2022` I have `394h 53m` remaining even though app is idle since `2022/04/23 23:36:32 +0200` so it was running for 30 more minutes without receiving web traffic...

Any idea what happened with all these dyno hours then? Or do I misunderstand how this works?

Comment: Do you have any scheduled jobs?

Comment: nope, and the output shows quite clearly that the dyno was idle since 2022/04/23 23:36:32 so how come the hours were used up?